# How Can I change the mouse cursor when hovering the specific part of the image in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created an application in ReactJS

HTML

`<div id="root"></div>`

React JS

```
function MouseCursor() {
    return(
        
            <div>
                <img src='https://usabilla.com/graphics/resources/usabilla-logo.png' style={{cursor: "wait", backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat", height: "160px",  width:"80%"}} />
                
                <p>Right Now the cursor image changes when overing the image</p>
            </div>
    
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MouseCursor />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

the jsfiddle for this code is :

https://jsfiddle.net/vewzyo2x/

When I hover the image the cursor changes, but I need to change the cursor of the mouse only when a certain part of the image is hovered
as shown in the below image
[image]

I need to change the cursor of the image only when the mouse is hovered on the circle shown in the above image. How can I do that?

Comment: First of all, you have sended domain of "jsfiddle"
In your case, my assumption is to use a svg. The svg has many elements and you can add ```id``` for your current element and handle it

Comment: And if SVG is not an option, you could position an empty DIV over that circle using `position:absolute` and put the mouse cursor only on that DIV.

Comment: Could you correct the link to your JS fiddle, thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry, the link to js fiddle is corrected. thank you

Comment: Will the image be stretched or squashed depending on the viewport width as you have it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you measure various distances on the image when the 'blob' is circular you get CSS to calculate what dimensions and what positioning (in % terms) the blob has in  relation to the whole image. As the image is stretched, the blob will stretch accordingly.

In this vanilla JS snippet the logo image is shown as the background to the div and the blob is its child div. This saves having to add another div into the DOM which wouldn't add more meaning.

The measurements were just taken with a ruler (the units don't matter)

```css
.usabilla {
  --h: 8.75;
  /* image height measured by a ruler */
  --w: 19.4;
  /* image width */
  --top: 1.5;
  /* position of the blob */
  --left: 11.7;
  --diam: 2;
  /* diameter of the blob (when the blob was circular) */
  width: 80%;
  height: 160px;
  background-image: url(https://usabilla.com/graphics/resources/usabilla-logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.blob {
  cursor: wait;
  height: calc(var(--diam) / var(--h) * 100%);
  width: calc(var(--diam) / var(--w) * 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--top) / var(--h) * 100%);
  left: calc(var(--left) / var(--w) * 100%);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="usabilla">
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked for me, but one question arises in my head. What If the portion where the cursor is to be changed is other than the circle case? Let's suppose instead of circle the requirement is to change the when u hover in S letter of the image. How to tackle that? just a question , my problem is solved already by circle way.

Comment: I guess you'd do something like use a mask-image on a rectangular div to get rid of the bits you don't want. See [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image or if it was a geometric shape you could use clip-path